# Saving IDA graphs as image

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

How Can I save `IDA Pro`'s normal graph view as image?
Is there any tool or plugin for that?

Comment: Which graphs? Proximity view? Normal graph view? Old graph view?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Normal Graph view

Comment: how about using PySide (`PySide 2011/12/30 for IDAPython 1.5+, Python 2.7 (2.6) and Qt 4.8.4 (IDA 6.5)`) from the download section on the Hex-Rays page and then asking in a developer Q&A (or forum) for the details about the Qt part?

Comment: You can also take a screenshot ;)

Comment: I think graph-easy is limited to Linux. I just tried installing to windows but haven't managed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save the graph as a .gdl file. You can then use [graph-easy](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/bin/graph-easy) to convert the GDL file to an image file such as SVG, PNG, JPG etc.

```
graph-easy --from gdl --input=graph.gdl --png --output=graph.png
```

Comment: I think graph-easy is limited to Linux. I just tried installing to windows but haven't managed it.

Comment: I can? How? I don't see any "Save as .gdl file" menus.