# How to make a screenshot of a graph view in IDA on Windows?

Tags: ida

Trying to save a big graph(the default graph view of assembly instructions in IDA after you press space in text view while viewing instructions of a function) as an image.

Googled this article: [Converting IDA Pro graphs to images](http://pank4j.github.io/posts/converting-ida-pro-graphs-to-images.html), it tells to use graph-easy for Linux, and saw this question: [Saving IDA graphs as image](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/saving-ida-graphs-as-image). The only answer suggests to use graph-easy for Linux. I'm on Windows. How to convert the graph to an image on Windows 10?

I googled how to convert gdl to image, too, and there's some ArchiCAD software for $3000 or something, and it looks like it's some big program for modeling or whatever. Then there's this online tool which doesn't work: https://fileproinfo.com/tools/viewer/gdl . Says the preview doesn't work. There's also: Stanford Microarray Database GDL Data . Their site is dead.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the image of the graph as it is displayed in IDA, you can use https://github.com/tmr232/GraphGrabber

For viewing and printing GDL graphs, you can use `qwingraph` program shipped with IDA.

There is also a “print graph” button on IDA’s graph toolbar but it’s not shown by default.

You can also generate graphs in a more common DOT format, see `ida.cfg` for the settings.